# iPhone view controller view shifted down 20 pixels when rotating to landscape

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, screen-rotation, rotatetransform

I am trying to implement a custom tabbarcontroller using a UIViewController and a UITabBar. Everything is working fine so far, except when I rotate the device to landscape, the UIViewController shifts the entire view down 20pixels, creating a black bar between the status bar and the view. Even when the view is rotated back to portrait orientation, the view is still shifted down 20pixels.

What do I need to do to remove the black bar? Do I have to perform custom rotations? If so, where should I insert these rotations?

Before rotation:
[image]

After rotation:
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITabBar appears 20 pixels down?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699404/uitabbar-appears-20-pixels-down), [Why do navigation appear 20 pixels below status bar in the view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850705/), [Why is my UITabBar shifting down 20 pixels when loaded on portrait?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997253/) [Launch Image off by 20 pixels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112697/), among [others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=landscape%20shift%2020%20pixels).

Answer (score 3):

I've experienced this same issue.

This discussion was helpful: [UIWebView on iPad size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194787/uiwebview-on-ipad-size)

[Tony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34101/tony)'s answer helped me discover that when you create a subview it's helpful to setup code similar to this:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
webView.frame = self.view.bounds;
```

If you post some of your code I may be able to provide more specific advice.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than shifting all views down, try DELTA properties in Interface builder.

[image]